# How to develop a gem in staging environment?

Tags: ruby, development-environment, rubygems, buildr

I am trying to hack through a forked gem (buildr). As such I cloned it from github and began to butcher the code. The official gem is installed on my system (under /usr/lib/ruby.../gems/buildr...). There is an executable which I need to use in my dev process - buildr.

Now I want the buildr executable and the library to point to my forked repo and not the default gem installation. This would be for this gem only. As such, the changes I make against the forked repo is usable directly for testing and so forth.

I would guess I need to load my library prior to the system gem loading. Can somebody recommend the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for work when the Spreadsheet gem broke backward compatibility. I put the previous versions code in it's own module and just renamed the gem my-spreadsheet and installed that (I really wanted some of the features of the new gem but I also didn't want to rewrite all my previous code at that point).

If it's just a binary you want to override you could always do some `PATH` magic, setting the directory of your binary first and thus make sure you always override. But personally I'd prefer making my own copy with a new name and installing that.

Answer (score 0):

you could bump the version in the gemspec for your fork. Then when you install your version of the gem, it will use your (newer) version by default.

change *buildr.gemspec*

```
#...
  spec.version        = '1.3.4.dev'
#...
```

Then

```
$ gem build buildr.gemspec
$ sudo gem install buildr-1.3.4.dev.gem
```

and it should work.

Comment: that would still mean I need to install the gem each time I do a change. Is it not possible to point gem to load the staging gem from the source instead of loading the installed one?

Comment: You could install it, then replace the `.../ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.4.dev` directory with a symlink to your source that you are modifying. It is pretty hacky, but would work. You'd want to be careful about permissions then.